# Regular expression to match different patterns

Tags: regex

Currently we are matching user input using the regular expression `([^=]*)(=[01])`. The user types a signal name (nnnann, where n is numeric and a is alphanumeric character) and its value, i.e. 0 or 1.

*Example: 101e10=1*

Now we have to extend the parser to also match the pattern t=N, where N means a number.

*Example: t=5000*

I tried to extend the regular expression to match both cases using `([^=]*)(=[01])|(^t)(=[0-9]*)`, but using this expression the first part already matches the pattern t=N .

How can I exclude the pattern **t** to be matched by the first part of the expression `[^=]*`?

I've already tried to subtract the pattern using `([^=]-[t]*)(=[01])|(^t)(=[0-9]*)` or `([^=]*-[t])(=[01])|(^t)(=[0-9]*)`, but both don't do the trick. Besides, I have the feeling that both tries are not the correct use of the subtract feature.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of lines that *would* match, and some lines that *wouldn't* match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps modify the first regex so that it's more strict on its validation.

```
([01]{3}[a-z][01]{2})(=[01])
```

And then combine with your second regex:

```
([01]{3}[a-z][01]{2})(=[01])|(^t)(=[0-9]*)
```

Or since you know that the first format starts with 0 or 1, you could do:

```
(^[01][^=]*)(=[01])|(^t)(=[0-9]*)
```

Comment: The stricter validation does exactly what I was looking for. *facepalm* that I didn't have the idea to make it more strict myself. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this:

```
(?:([0-9][^=]*)(=[01])|(t)(=[0-9]*))
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. This works for t=N where N's first character is not 1. t=1000 will again be matched by the first part.

Comment: @PVitt how about now?